# Problems with Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers: Gmaps.map is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am trying to dynamically change the markers in Gmaps4Rails based on a user search form. I am using the code below.

The problem I am encountering is that the call to Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers within $('#locations_search').submit gives an error: Gmaps.map is undefined.

I checked using the javascript debbuger, and indeed once I enter the submit function (I have a breakpoint there), Gmaps.map is undefined. When stopping with a breakpoint in the first lines of Gmaps.map.callback, the object Gmaps.map is defined.

Probably I am missing something. It seems to be some variable scope problem here?

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {

  var firstMarker = Gmaps.map.markers[0];
  var map         = Gmaps.map.map;
  firstMarker.infowindow.open(map, firstMarker.serviceObject);

  $('#locations_search').submit(function () {
    var url = '/locations.json/?' + $(this).serialize();
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(data);
            });
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a question of script order.

`Gmaps.map` is created in your view when
You call either `gmaps` or `gmaps4rails` helpers.

Solution:

- Add your scripts **after** your call to the gem's helpers
- wrap your js code in `<% content_for :scripts do %>  code <% end %>`

---

in your view:

```
<%= gmaps(...) %>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  Gmaps.map.callback = function() { ... }
</script>
<% end %>
```

---

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {

  var namespace   = Gmaps.map;
  var firstMarker = namespace.markers[0];
  var map         = namespace.map;
  firstMarker.infowindow.open(map, firstMarker.serviceObject);

  $('#locations_search').submit(function () {
    var url = '/locations.json/?' + $(this).serialize();
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            namespace.replaceMarkers(data);
        });
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Can you elaborate this, I still couldn't get it work unfortunately. What do you mean by "Add your scripts after your call to the gem's helpers"? Where is that, in my view?

The code above is in my view locations/index.html.erb, and at the very end of the file (i.e. after the call `<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @json } ) %>`, and wrapped with `<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript"> [... my code ...] </script> <% end %>`

Comment: Mmmh, I think that's how I do it. 

The error I get is: Gmaps.map undefined, in the line `getJSON...` in my code above.

Comment: could you copy/paste the html of your page in some gist?

Comment: Yes, that does it!!!! You're amazing :) Thanks a lot for your quick and kind help!